# Reindex from different computer

Tags: magento2, reindex, indexing, index, magento-cron

Ok so basically I have been given this one task to manage the admin side for a website that used Magento 2. But then, I have encountered some problem with the reindexing. I have been searching about it for days. The problem here is i dont even know where Magento 2 is being installed because i only have admin access. Is there any way to reindex on different computer? Im still new to this can any of you help me?

Comment: From Admin you can not re-index, You need ssh access for run command `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: thank you!!! ive been trying that but the access got denied perhaps i need to contact the developer team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In magento2, if you want to do indexing you need  SSh access of your server. From admin,you cannot reindex. Also magento cron should configure properly at server.Then the indexing problem will be resolved.

Comment: i see thank you for your answer. My thoughts were right. I have to ask for the developer team because i think they have the access so thank you again!!

Answer (score 0):

No, as an admin user you are not allowed to re-index from the backend (admin panel) when in production mode, since Magento 2.x. versions. You are allowed to [re-index only from the shell / cli using magento CLI commands](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-index.html#configure-indexers) or [by configuring cron jobs for the respective indexers.](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html)

> bin/magento indexer:reindex [indexer]

If you want to have the reindexing feature available for admin users then ask your development team to install the respective extensions, which enables this feature for admin users.

https://marketplace.magento.com/bsscommerce-reindex-data.html

Hope this helps.

**Note:** am not affiliated to the extension i recommended.